# Building ODK 1.16.4 failing on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I have been trying to build this repository in Android Studio but to no avail https://github.com/getodk/collect/releases/tag/v1.16.4

Building with the gradle wrapper gradle-wrapper.properties gives me an "`Unsupported class file major version 55`" (using Gradle JVM Java 8 / Gradle wrapper : 4.7)

I change gradle JVM to Java 11 and wrapper to 4.9 then I get this error :

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':collect_app'.
java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
```

I use the latest *Android studio Bumblebee*

Anyone can help please?

**Edit**

After hours of retries, I finally managed to get it running, by installing an older version of android studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of retries, I finally managed to get it running, by installing an older version of android studio.

Comment: Make sure to update the original post to let everyone know!